# Map activity test works only with one device

Tags: google-maps

I'm getting struggled since yesterday with an issue that i found inexplicable . 
When i test my map activity on a android device which run on jelly bean (api 17) it works fine with no probleme , but when i try to start the same activity with other device ( Nexus 4 api 21 and Xperia Z api 19 ) the app crashes and no message in the logcat !! After searching , i add some lines to my manifest : `

```
    <uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21"
    android:maxSdkVersion="21" />`
```

but nothing wanna run ! if someone can help , it will be great !

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolve my probleme , i had to update my build tool version to 22.0 (i used to work with the 21.01.1) , it looks weird but this updating fix my issue !